# Powershell pattern search - I need to search by date as well

Tags: powershell, date, elasticsearch, search, full-text-search

I need to not only find the item in my logs, `cat * | Select-String "ITEM"`, but the `DATE` of the log so I can search it for other info I know appeared based on the `ITEM` being there.

`cat * | Select-String "helix" $date`, did not work.

Please help.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Please update your question to show representative sample lines from your logs. In general, a search pattern must be passed as a _single_ argument.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Mom. Is the "date" you seek in the file or is it the LastWriteTime of the file? Can you say more about "(did not work)?" Based on reading `help Select-String -Full`, "helix" is in position 0 as the -Pattern and "$date" is in position 1 interpreted as the -Path.

Comment: cat * | Select-String "helix" worked to send return ALL the instances where the word "helix" showed up in the LOGS.

cat * | Select-String "helix" $date did not work, it returned an error. 

I need it to show me the date of the log it if found in   ie:  "ShadylDR_2021-12-21"  It is pulling the character name, the game name then the date.  Every day you play the game, it compounds all logins to one file. 

Does that explain it better?

Comment: The date the log was created, for instance.. Logs are created this way: 

LOG folder
GiabellaDR_2021-12-21
GiabellaDR_2021-12-21

cat * | Select-String "helix" 
returns all instances of helix found in the LOG folder, but it does not tell me the DATE to then go search that log.  

cat * | Select-String "helix" $date   --- did not work to tell me the date of that log

Can you please tell me the proper search to have the date?